# Why do tau2 and I2 estimations differ between frequentists and Bayesian models

Tags: bayesian, meta-analysis, frequentist, heterogeneity

I was conducting a network metanalysis of treatments and found out that I2 and tau2 esitmates are widely different between the models (as an example, for the same outcome, I have a tau2= 0.0078 and I2= 12.2% [0.0 - 46.6%] with the frequentist model and tau2= 87.4 and I2= 99.8 [98.9 - 99.9]).

How can this be possible? Am I calcualting it wrong?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Edit: Here is the code for the Bayesian imputation:

```
model{                            
for(i in 1:ns){                     
  h[i,1] <- 0    
  delta[i,1] <- 0           
  mu[i] <- log(p[i,1])
  p[i,1] ~ dunif(0,1)     
  for (k in 1:na[i]) {             
    r[i,k] ~ dbin(p[i,k],n[i,k]) 
   }
  for (k in 2:na[i]) {             
    log(p[i,k]) <- mu[i] + min(delta[i,k], -log(p[i,1]))
    delta[i,k] ~ dnorm(md[i,k],taud[i,k])
    md[i,k] <-  d[t[i,k]] - d[t[i,1]] + w1[i,k]*fw1 + w2[i,k]*fw2 + sh[i,k]
    taud[i,k] <- tau.d *2*(k-1)/k
    h[i,k] <- delta[i,k] - (d[t[i,k]] + d[t[i,1]] + w1[i,k]*fw1 + w2[i,k]*fw2)
    sh[i,k] <- sum(h[i,1:(k-1)])/(k-1)
   }
 } 


sd ~ dunif(0,2)    
tau.d <- pow(sd,-2)  

fw1 ~ dnorm(0, tau.d)
fw2 ~ dnorm(0, tau.d)  

d[1]<-0
for (k in 2:nt){  d[k] ~ dnorm(0,.1) }

for (c in 1:(nt-1)) {  
  for (k in (c+1):nt)  { 
      lnRR[c,k]<- d[c] - d[k]
      RR[c,k]<- exp(d[c]-d[k])
      lnRR[k,c]<- d[k] - d[c]
      RR[k,c]<- exp(d[k]-d[c])
   }  
 }

rk_bad<-rank(d[])
```

And the R code to calculate I2 from the posterior distribution:

```
tau2<-res$BUGSoutput$sims.matrix[,"tau.d"]
I2.cons<-tau2/(tau2+mean(na.omit(sei_All_cause^2)))
median(tau2)
median(I2.cons)
```

Comment: What model? Software? command? what type of data?

Comment: Hi Jacob, it is a random-effect trial level network metanalysis with a design-by-treatment interaction as suggested by Higghins for the Bayesian and a standard random-effects network metanalysis for the frequentist model. 
Software is R with netmeta for the frequentist model and JAGS through R by using runJAGS.

Comment: Estimates should be similar or at least within the sample range. It is unclear the outcome and how large your network is.

Comment: In general, the outcomes are binary outcomes (like all cause death), the estimate is risk ratio and the network is quite large and mostly indirect (i.e., more than ten nodes, more than 50.000 observations in total)